# How to use String#scan using regular expressions by digit length and keep odd remainder as element

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to separate a string in units of three, but also have the remainder as a separate element.

```
def separate(string)
  string.scan(/\w{3}/)
end
```

So, if I pass in "BENISME" I want it to return [BEN][ISM] and then also [E]
I know there is an easy answer to this, but for the life of me I just cant figure it out! What would I add to this to return the remaining E?

Answer (score 2):

```
def separate(string)
  string.scan(/\w{1,3}/) # => ["BEN", "ISM", "E"]
end
```

Basically, `{n,m}` in regexen means "any amount of times between `n` and `m`."

This will always take the maximum amount of characters it can (it will always give you three characters if possible), because regex is "greedy," and always tries to take as much as possible. Unless you use the non-greedy modifier, like so:

```
string.scan(/\w{1,3}?/) # => ["B", "E", "N", "I", "S", "M", "E"]
```

Comment: This is a good answer and works, but you should explain why it will reliably chunk in 3's instead of in 1's, 2's, or purely arbitrary amounts.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure It's because regex is "greedy," and always tries to take as much as possible (unless you use the non-greedy modifier, as in `/\w{1,3}?/`).

Comment: Excellent. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regular expressions at all? You could do `each_slice` on the character array:

```
def separate(string)
  string.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join).to_a
end
```

Comment: What if the string contains non-word (not `A-Z a-z _`) characters? Also, you'll have to add `.map(&:join)` to get strings instead of charcter arrays in the output.

Comment: Requirements were not clear on how to deal with non-word characters. My answer purely answers the question of how to split a string into chunks of three. The example suggests it would be used for single-word strings.